# declaring a variable with colon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, flowtype

Hi right now i'm learning JavaScript. There is a confusion with some JavaScript I just found. This is the source code

```
import type { OptionsType } from 'Types'

const theme: OptionsType = {
  title: 'Lawton',
  baseFontSize: '16px',
  baseLineHeight: 1.5
}
```

In the code, the const variable is declared with **":"**

What does **":"** mean in the expression ?

Is it equivalent with

```
const theme = OptionsType = { title: 'Lawton' }
```

Comment: looks like invalid javascript - perhaps this is typescript?

Comment: This is typescript. The `:` is for the `type`. In this case, you are declaring `theme` as a `OptionsType`

Answer (score 5):

> What does ":" mean in the expression ?

This is FlowType. Checkout the docs on the annotation: https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/

## More

This is not TypeScript as `import type` is a flow thing: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/#importing-and-exporting-types-a-classtoc-idtoc-importing-and-exporting-types-hreftoc-importing-and-exporting-typesa

Comment: Thx basarat this is right. 
I omitted to copy // @flow at the top of the source code, didn't think it involve with the problems.